# Кавычки и их применение

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно выделять кавычками названия произведений и цитаты писателей? В чем разница между комбинациями нижняя кавычка - текст - верхняя кавычка и верхняя кавычка - текст - верхняя кавычка.

Comment: Лучше на примере. А так — вопрос слишком общий.

Answer (score 2):

Названия произведений и цитаты обязательно берутся в кавычки.

По поводу типов кавычек сошлюсь на книгу С. М. Львовского «Набор и верстка в системе LaTeX»: в русском языке традиционными считаются кавычки-«ёлочки» в качестве внешних и кавычки–„лапки“ в качестве внутренних (например, когда внутри цитаты слово берётся в кавычки). Отдельного символа для ещё более внутренних кавычек нет: используется тот же, что и для внутренних. Впрочем, это достаточно редкий случай.

У американцев принято в качестве внешних использовать “двойные”, а в качестве внутренних — ‘одиночные’ кавычки. (Обратите внимание, что закрывающая внутренняя кавычка-„лапка“ в точности совпадает с открывающей, но не закрывающей “двойной”.) У англичан — наоборот: в качестве внешних ‘одиночные’, а в качестве внутренних — “двойные” кавычки (см. [здесь](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/british-versus-american-style.html)). В обоих случаях при использовании печатных машинок ставили машинописные "двойные" и 'одиночные' кавычки.

P. S. Если не видно разницы между англоамериканскими «правильными» и машинописными кавычками, можно увеличить масштаб.

Answer (score 1):

О  Правилах, которые не выдержат пересказа, здесь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=169.

О форме и типографике кратко здесь: https://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/104/.

Массу примеров найдёте на этом сайте через окно Поиска, набрав слово *кавычки*.